# iOS Core Data Migration big Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

when i started developing the app, I had a **Core data model** with **5 Entities** (named `Visitors, UnreadMessages, ContactStatuses, UserVCard` and `User`). The app went live on app store.. no issue in that.. Now i had to add some requirement changes so the core data model changed minorly by having **2 more entities** added to it (named `AudioSupportedWindows` and `AudioMessages`)

So according to a lot of articles, SO posts, and apple documentation, The way to migrate this was **LightWeight migration** so for that I added the following code

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,    
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

NSError *error;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];

if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType        configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    // Handle error
    NSLog(@"Problem with PersistentStoreCoordinator: %@",error);
}
```

in my `persistentStoreCoordinator` method. But it always gives a **`Can't find model for source store`** error.

After that I started of with manual migration using a migration mapping according to this link [Core Data - Default Migration ( Manual )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170064/core-data-default-migration-manual)

But when i run this I get both source and destination models but they are identical that is they both consisting on 5 entities. and i get this error **`The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store`**

terribly em in deep trouble ryt now solving this… any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit 1

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"UserData" withExtension:@"momd"];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

Comment: You must never ever change the data model of your app after it has been deployed to users. You need to create a new version of the model so that they are both in the app. If you have changed it, you need to go back to a previous version of your code (with git or whatever you are using for versioning), or from a previous backup. Then try again with both models included in your app.

Comment: THats a really weird thing you are saying that never to change the data model.. there can be requirement changes or additions to the application.. you'll then definitely need to change the model.

Comment: No, you are saying that your app is live on the app store. Then you presumably have multiple users using your app with your current data model. If you need to change that data model, you can't just change your current model, as that will disable your app from using the current core data store (since the data model no longer matches the store). What I am saying is that you need to create a new version (a copy) in xcode, and then change the copy. This way, your app now includes TWO versions of the data model: the one used in the apps your users have, and the new model you want to migrate to

Comment: What he said is that you must not change your data model but instead create a new version of it and modifying the new version.

Comment: ohk.. so Still the issue is of migrating the model to the changed model..

Comment: How is [self managedObjectModel] implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help… I solved it using lightweight migration.. what i did was delete my xcdatamodeld, recreate it from the one on App Store, make new database file, add new model version.. Somehow  i have no clue how it got working…

but em happy it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the original model and the new model are both included in your app, in a model bundle. You can’t just include the new model and expect it to migrate (although that would be cooler), it’s not the way it works.

Your new model should be marked as the “current model.” Your old one is so the old file can still be read. If there are no required new fields in the new model that weren’t in the old one, the lightweight translation should work.

Comment: i have both the model files in the `xcdatamodeld` and the newer one is selected as the current model..

Comment: Did you build from clean (hail mary)?

Comment: I downloaded the version on app store, used that application, Then deployed the application using Xcode on to the device with the new versioned model.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your model you think you have released is different from the one you actually did.
To check what did you submit to iTC:

- go to Organizer/Archives find the archive you submitted then 'Show in Finder'
- find the model version file: *VersionInfo.plist*
- open the plist have a look into the the hash value for each entity

Comparing the hash value with hash values of your current model (just create a fresh archive) you should be able to find the one which has changed.

Comment: the entities that are in both versions have same hash values.. the only difference in them is the entities that are added in the newer version.

Comment: one more thing, idk if it matters or not, there are 4 files there instead of 3 **UserData.mom, UserData 2.mom, VersionInfo.plist and UserData 2.omo**

Comment: In the VersionInfo.plist you should have two models: one with the original 5 entities and 'Model 2' with 7 entities.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an issue I've run a few times. Download your app from the app store and run it so it creates the managed object store. Then in your xcode **before** instantiating your persistent store coordinator try the following:

```
// Model.momd/Model is the path of the previous model. Make sure it's correct
NSURL *oldUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Model.momd/Model"] withExtension:@"mom"];
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:oldUrl];
NSLog(@"Old model version hashes: %@", model.entityVersionHashesByName);

// Change model with your model name
NSURL *currentModelUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Model"] withExtension:@"momd"];
NSManagedObjectModel *currentModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:currentModelUrl];
NSLog(@"Current model version hashes: %@", currentModel.entityVersionHashesByName);



// storeUrl is the path to the persistent store, created by the app store version
NSDictionary *metadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:NSSQLiteStoreType URL:storeUrl error:nil];
NSLog(@"Store metadata: %@", metadata);
```

Metadata entity hashes should be identical to your old model version hashes. If they are not, then the original model you have and the one you've shipped with are different. You might need to find your old model in your source control repo (hope you have one), otherwise you can try changing those values by hand.

Comment: just did this… no difference in 5 entities hash values, only difference is the newly added 2 entities in current model hash value.

Comment: So the difference between the old model and the current model is exactly the 2 new entities, and the metadata is exactly as the old model ?

Comment: Hm, then you shouldn't have that problem at all

Comment: thats what is killing me… i can't seem to find any problem but it won't migrate