# Core Data Migration - Changing Attribute Type

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I have an iOS application that is using Core Data Persistent Store.  I have a few people testing the application and need to make some changes to the data model, specifically changing the type of an attribute from 'NSString' to 'int16_t'.

Here is what I have done so far:

- Created a new model version
- Changed the attribute type
- Added a mapping model (I am not sure what I need in here.  I have my one EntityMapping with a Custom Policy)
- Created the Custom Policy (listed below)

I am using MagicalRecord.  The migration is being performed, but seems to be clearing the database.  I am able to read the SQLite file locally and can see the table column changes (but not on everytime I clean, load old app version, and perform migration).

How can I get something like this to work?  I would like to dynamically read the string and compute the correct it value. Right now I am setting it to 1 as a NSNumber.  I am not sure how to create a valid NSExpression for an int

Here is my Custom Policy :

```
@implementation MessageLabelMigration

- (BOOL)createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:(NSManagedObject *)instance
                                  entityMapping:(NSEntityMapping *)mapping
                                        manager:(NSMigrationManager *)manager
                                          error:(NSError **)error {
    NSArray *_properties = [mapping attributeMappings];
    NSLog(@"_properties: %@", _properties);

    for (NSPropertyMapping *_property in _properties) {
        if ([[_property name] isEqualToString:@"label"]) {
            NSExpression *_expression = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:1]];
            [_property setValueExpression:_expression];
        }
    }

    return [super createDestinationInstancesForSourceInstance:instance
                                            entityMapping:mapping
                                                  manager:manager
                                                    error:error];
}

@end
```

Comment: See Nick Weaver's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995231/example-or-explanation-of-core-data-migration-with-multiple-passes