# Core Data Migration with MagicalRecord - add attribute and fill it

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration, magicalrecord

I have an iOS app and I have some problems with UITableView and section headers using MagicalRecord. I need to sort my table by title and the title has entries with uppercase and lowercase letters. Since MagicalRecord does not do "ignoreCase" sorting I need to have an additional column with a "normalized" title (e.g. all lowercase).

Now my issue is how to add this additional column. I can add a new column through the migration, but I do not know how to fill the column with the normalized title.

I read this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995231/example-or-explanation-of-core-data-migration-with-multiple-passes) but can still not figure out how this should work.

I am already thinking of writing my own migration system as I know it from Rails that would just fill the new column with the normalized title.

If you are interested: the source for the whole project is on GitHub:
https://github.com/deepflame/iOpenSongs

Comment: Do you still need help with this issue or have you solved it?

Comment: @runmad thanks for asking. I have solved it now with some custom migration. Will add a solution for that later.

Comment: @runmad  would you guys share a solution? How do you solve this ?