# App Crashes because of Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, crash

My app update got accepted today and it is crashing when you try to open it. The only way it stops crashing is if you delete it and re-install it. I think the reason the app is crashing is because whenever I make a change to a entity in Core Data and create a new NSManagedObjectClass. The crash message:

```
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
```

According to this answer:[The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881453/the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the)

I have to delete the app and clean the project. Now that the update is on the app store what do I do to fix it? Do the users have to delete the app? Is that the only way?

Thank you,

Abdullah Shafique

Comment: You have two options: 1. Hope users try to delete it and reinstall it which probably won't happen 2. Do what Neal said and migrate the database. I would suggest rejecting the update if it hasn't made it through review yet and plug in the migration code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you changed your data model. You need to migrate your data. Directions to do so are [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995231/example-or-explanation-of-core-data-migration-with-multiple-passes). You should put out a hotfix as soon as possible to add a migration path.